# Bibliography request for differential equation involving Dedekind Eta Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, modular-forms

I would like to find the reference or bibliographic source of the fact that the following differential equation:

$$36(y')^2-24y''y+y''' = 0$$

is satisfied by $y(z) = \frac{\eta'(z)}{\eta(z)}$ ($\eta(z)$ denotes Dedekind eta function).

I have found this ODE in [Wolfram Functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/DedekindEta/13/01/). After a while searching around the internet, I have not found any reference.

Thank you.

Comment: Since $y(z)$ is $E_2(z)$ up to a constant factor, look for ODE for $E_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one reference and there must be others. The arXiv article
[Integrable systems and modular forms of level 2](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609210) by Ablowitz, Chakravarty and Hanh on page 2 give an ODE
$$ y''' = 2yy'' - 3y'^2, \tag{1.2} $$
and note that it is related to Darboux-Halphen and Chazy. They remark that

> Indeed, a particular solution of $(1.2)$ is given by $$ y(z) :=\pi i E_2(z),$$

Now we have $\,\eta'(z)/\eta(z) = \frac{2\pi i}{24} E_2(z)\,$ which leads to the ODE you give in your question. Now $E_2(z)$ is a quasi-modular form and is closely related to the modular forms $E_4(z)$ and $E_6(z)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not realise I should search for $E_2$

Comment: And what is the argument to show $E_2$ satisfies such an ODE ?

Comment: @reuns The argument is contained either in the linked arXiv article or its references.

Comment: The 123 of modular forms p.49 shows it follows from relations between $E_4,E_6,E_2,E_4',E_6',E_2'$ following from the modular derivative $f' - \frac{k}{12} E_2 \in M_{k+2}(\Gamma)$ if $f \in M_k(\Gamma)$